# Substring and case statements in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am converting SQL to LINQ. Can someone help how to achieve the substring and case statements like below in LINQ.

```
SELECT p.goalcommitment, 
       g.goalmeasurement,
       CASE g.goalmeasurement 
           WHEN 'Count' THEN CAST(p.goalcommitmentnumber AS VARCHAR)
           WHEN 'Currency' THEN '$' + CAST(p.goalcommitmentcurrency AS VARCHAR)
           WHEN 'Percentage' THEN RTRIM(CAST(p.goalcommitmentpercentage AS VARCHAR)) + '%'
           ELSE p.pamwb_goalcommitment 
       END AS goalcommitment,
       SUBSTRING(p.domainname, CHARINDEX('\', p.domainname, 0) + 1, LEN(p.domainname) - CHARINDEX('\', p.domainname, 0))    
FROM Filtered_psp p
JOIN Filtered_goalsubtype g 
ON g.goalsubtypeid = p.goalsubtype
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your sql will look like in linq:

```
var query = from p in Filtered_psp
            join g in Filtered_goalsubtype on p.goalsubtype equals g.goalsubtypeid
            let slashLocation = p.domainname.IndexOf(@"\")
            select new
            {
                Field1 = p.goalcommitment,
                Field2 = g.goalmeasurement,
                Field3 = (p.goalmeasurement == "Count" ? p.goalcommitmentnumber.ToString() :
                          p.goalmeasurement == "Currency" ? "$" + p.goalcommitmentnumber.ToString() :
                          p.goalmeasurement == "Percentage" ? p.goalcommitmentnumber.ToString() + "%" : p.pamwb_goalcommitment),
                Field4 = slashLocation == -1 ? (p.domainname : p.domainname.Substring(slashLocation + 1, p.domainname.Length - slashLocation - 1)))
            };
```

Comment: Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length This is the Exception which iam getting.      If this is the Domian Name "Google\youtube "  My expectation is Only "youtube"

Comment: Not yet Iam not able to get the domainame As expected which is returning -1

Comment: Gilad Green Thank You

Comment: @PankajErrolla - what was the problem at the end?

Comment: AliasName = p.DomainName == null ? null : p.DomainName.Substring(p.DomainName.IndexOf(@"@") + 1, p.DomainName.Length -p.DomainName.IndexOf(@"@")-1), this wayi resolved my problem and now facing issue with the Group by from two different  tables how do we do that

Comment: @Ah ok I haven't realized that `p.DomainName` might be `null`

Comment: from ci in orgContext.CreateQuery<tabl1>() join pc_mp in orgContext.CreateQuery<table3>()
 on ci.Id equals pc_mp.id into gr
                                  from leftJoin in gr.DefaultIfEmpty()                                
                                   join mp in orgContext.CreateQuery<table3>()
                                  on leftJoin.id equals mp.rId            select new{} can you please   help me on this iam getting an exception select to many is not supported followed by Join

Comment: @PankajErrolla - Please post it in a new question. If you'd like specifically me to help you with it then you can tag me in a comment